# How to import Apache Kafka in OSGi / Karaf

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, apache-karaf, apache-felix, onos

I am trying to import and use Apache Kafka producer within an application of a much bigger project ([onosproject.org](http://onosproject.org/)) developed with Karaf. My application is referencing four services of which only one is satisfied, resulting in unsatisfied component:

```
onos> scr:list | grep com.foo.bar
115 | UNSATISFIED | com.foo.bar.AppComponent
```

After removing the code that required the three unsatisfied service I got the same behaviour which looks even stranger.

```
onos> scr:details com.foo.bar.AppComponent 
Component Details
  Name                : com.foo.bar.AppComponent
  State               : UNSATISFIED
  Properties          : 
    service.pid=com.foo.bar.AppComponent
    component.name=com.foo.bar.AppComponent
    component.id=115
References
  Reference           : hostService
    State             : satisfied
    Multiple          : single
    Optional          : mandatory
    Policy            : static
    Service Reference : Bound Service ID 1023 (org.onosproject.net.host.impl.HostManager)
```

Judging from logs, activation works fine which makes me believe that something in `pom.xml` 's dependencies is incorrect. I am building using servicemix:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.2_1</version>
</dependency>
```

with maven-bundle-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>net.jpountz*;version="[1.2.0,1.3.0)";resolution:=optional,
                javax.management*,
                org.slf4j*;resolution:=optional,
                org.xerial.snappy;resolution:=optional,
                sun.misc;resolution:=optional,
                sun.nio.ch;resolution:=optional
            </Import-Package>
            <Export-Package>
                org.apache.kafka.*
            </Export-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know if I have to, but I also exposing servicemix bundle via `features.xml`:

```
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients/0.8.2.2_1</bundle>
```

I have also tried building with `org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.2` instead the servicemix but I had the same behavior.
Please find a much more detailed description of my tries/logs in this [github repo](https://github.com/kyrsideris/failing-onos-app-puzzle).

Any suggestions will be appreciated! :)